# How to Connect a Find/Search Step to an Update Step

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

On a `zapier-cli` application, how do I do to create the `Add a search step` button next to a dynamic field that will be used to fill the ID of the object about to be updated, like in the image shown below, described on Zapier's documentation here https://zapier.com/help/how-connect-findsearch-step-update-step/ ?

[image]

This is my `InputField` definition:

```
{
        key: "contact_id",
        type: "string",
        label: 'Contact',
        required: true,
        helpText: "Pick the contact to update.",
        dynamic: "contact.id.name",
        altersDynamicFields: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Per [the docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#search-powered-fields) you need to add a `search` property that points to a search key and id property (like `findContact.id`). That plus `dynamic` will get you your search button.